# pass javascript var to classic asp function as parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

I have a page which fetches 2 tables from 2 different pages via ajax call (JQuery is NOT used)

I want to know how many rows are returned from each page, by searching the returned inner html response for tr entries.

and then set the record count to a variable (in asp) (the result yielding of the xmlhttp request by using regular expression to count tr entries)

because I need to do if-condition and handle an issue based on the records count

here's a simplified sample of what I need: (not working)

```
<%
dim hi
hi ="hi there"

function hiFunc (val)
hiFunc = val
end function
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp ;
function test()
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET", "somepage.asp?q=blablabla", true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = 
function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
{

var hi ="<%=hiFunc(xmlhttp.responseText)%>";
alert("test: \n<%=hi%>");
}
       }           

}
```

Is this doable?

Appreciate your cooperation.

Comment: ASP code is rendered on the server before the page loads, Client side JS is rendered by the browser after the page loads, so any variables which come out of your JS would need to be submitted back to the server as either a querystring or a form collection. Looking at your code though you may be able to do everything server side. You can certainly use ASP to create a Microsoft.XMLHTTP object, ASP is basically about using Active X objects server side. You can even use javascript for your server side code. (strictly JScript but there's very little difference).

Comment: No.  You are writing code for two different computers, the web server (asp) and the client (javascript) - the only way those two computers can communicate/share data is via HTTP requests.